# Plot discontinued/broken axis with gap in the x axis indicating scale jump

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I am trying to plot several ranges of my data into the same plot with plotly. For example the xaxis shall cover the ranges [0,14],[520,540] and [850,890]. However, when taking these data into one plot, there will be huge empty gaps inbetween the data regions, as the plot will simply cover the complete range from [0,890]. Due to this scaling the individual features of the data will be compresed to the point were nothing is discernible.

What I what to achieve is something like in this image:

[image]

Is it even possible to plot such a discontinued axis? If anybody also know how this discontinuation is called or if there is a name for that, I would be interested to hear it

Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no *direct* way to do this with plotly. But with a little creativity you can easily make a setup that should come pretty close to what you're asking for. *And* save you from the pain of static matplotlib approaches. I'll spare you the details in case the following figure is not to your liking. But if it is, then I don't mind explaining the details. You'll find most of the details in the comments in the complete code snippet below though.

#### Plot 1:

[image]

#### Code 1:

```
# imports
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

# data
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'years': [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000,],
                  'China': [219, 146, 112, 127, 124, 180],
                  'Rest of world': [16, 13, 10, 11, 28, 37]}).set_index('years')

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'years': [2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013,],
                  'China': [207, 236, 263,350, 430, 474],
                  'Rest of world': [43, 55, 56, 88, 105, 156]}).set_index('years')

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'years': [2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022],
                  'China': [488, 537, 500, 439, 444, 555],
                  'Rest of world': [299, 340, 403, 549, 300, 311]}).set_index('years')
# df.set_index('years', inplace = True)

# organize datafames with different x-axes in a dict
dfs = {'df1': df1,
       'df2': df2,
       'df3': df3}

# subplot setup
colors = px.colors.qualitative.Plotly
fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=len(dfs.keys()), horizontal_spacing = 0.02)
fig.update_layout(title = "Broken / discontinued / gapped x-axis")

# Assign columns from dataframes in dict to the correct subplot
for i, dfd in enumerate(dfs, start =1):
    for j, col in enumerate(dfs[dfd].columns):
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=dfs[dfd].index,
                        y=dfs[dfd][col],
                        name=col,
                        marker_color=colors[j],
                        legendgroup = col,
                        showlegend = True if i == 1 else False,
                        ), row=1, col=i)

# this section is made specifically for this dataset
# and this number of dataframes but can easily
# be made flexible wrt your data if this setup
# if something you can use
fig.update_yaxes(range=[0, 750])
fig.update_yaxes(showticklabels=False, row=1, col=2)
fig.update_yaxes(showticklabels=False, row=1, col=3)

# and just a little aesthetic adjustment
# that's admittedly a bit more challenging
# to automate...
# But entirely possible =D
fig.add_shape(type="line",
    x0=0.31, y0=-0.01, x1=0.33, y1=0.01,
    line=dict(color="grey",width=1),
    xref = 'paper',
    yref = 'paper'
)

fig.add_shape(type="line",
    x0=0.32, y0=-0.01, x1=0.34, y1=0.01,
    line=dict(color="grey",width=1),
    xref = 'paper',
    yref = 'paper'
)

fig.add_shape(type="line",
    x0=0.66, y0=-0.01, x1=0.68, y1=0.01,
    line=dict(color="grey",width=1),
    xref = 'paper',
    yref = 'paper'
)

fig.add_shape(type="line",
    x0=0.67, y0=-0.01, x1=0.69, y1=0.01,
    line=dict(color="grey",width=1),
    xref = 'paper',
    yref = 'paper'
)

fig.update_layout(template='plotly_white')
fig.show()
```