# Squeeze x-axis dates on altair line chart

Tags: python, datetime, streamlit, altair

I have a burndown graph that shows dates on the x-axis and remaining objects on the y-axis. Sometimes I have a large amount of "stagnant" data (no objects completed for X-amount of time). The stagnant data is overpowering the line chart and viewers are more interested in the end part of the line chart. Given two known dates, is there a way to squeeze a range of x-axis dates?

There is much more data, but here is a quick reproducible example (using streamlit as well).

```
import datetime
import streamlit as st
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

x_values = [datetime.date(2022, 1, 7), datetime.date(2022, 1, 28), datetime.date(2022, 1, 29), datetime.date(2022, 1, 30), datetime.date(2022, 1, 31), datetime.date(2022, 2, 1), datetime.date(2022, 2, 2), datetime.date(2022, 2, 3), datetime.date(2022, 2, 4), datetime.date(2022, 2, 5), datetime.date(2022, 2, 6), datetime.date(2022, 2, 7), datetime.date(2022, 2, 8), datetime.date(2022, 2, 9), datetime.date(2022, 2, 10), datetime.date(2022, 2, 11), datetime.date(2022, 2, 12),datetime.date(2022, 12, 8), datetime.date(2023, 8, 20), datetime.date(2023, 8, 21), datetime.date(2023, 8, 22), datetime.date(2023, 8, 23), datetime.date(2023, 8, 24), datetime.date(2023, 8, 25), datetime.date(2023, 8, 26), datetime.date(2023, 8, 27), datetime.date(2023, 8, 28), datetime.date(2023, 8, 29), datetime.date(2023, 8, 30), datetime.date(2023, 8, 31), datetime.date(2023, 9, 1), datetime.date(2023, 9, 2), datetime.date(2023, 9, 3), datetime.date(2023, 9, 4), datetime.date(2023, 9, 5), datetime.date(2023, 9, 6), datetime.date(2023, 9, 7), datetime.date(2023, 9, 8), datetime.date(2023, 9, 9)]

y_values = [3521, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 1808.695652173913, 1417.391304347826, 1417.391304347826, 1417.391304347826, 1026.086956521739, 634.782608695652, 243.47826086956502, 0]

# Burndown line graph
line_data = pd.DataFrame({'x': x_values, 'y': y_values})

chart_width = 400
chart_height = 600

line_chart = alt.Chart(line_data).mark_line().encode(
    x=alt.X('x:T', axis=alt.Axis(title='Date', grid=True, ticks=True, tickCount=12,
                                    format='%Y-%m-%d', labelAngle=-45, tickColor='pink', tickSize=10, tickWidth=3)),

    y=alt.Y('y:Q', axis=alt.Axis(title='Tiles'))
)
st.altair_chart(line_chart, use_container_width=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hacky, but you can create two separate charts side by side by filtering the data before and after the known dates. For the right chart, we can set the domain of the yaxis to be the same as the left chart, then remove the title and ticks from the y-axis to clean up the appearance.

```
import datetime
import streamlit as st
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

x_values = [datetime.date(2022, 1, 7), datetime.date(2022, 1, 28), datetime.date(2022, 1, 29), datetime.date(2022, 1, 30), datetime.date(2022, 1, 31), datetime.date(2022, 2, 1), datetime.date(2022, 2, 2), datetime.date(2022, 2, 3), datetime.date(2022, 2, 4), datetime.date(2022, 2, 5), datetime.date(2022, 2, 6), datetime.date(2022, 2, 7), datetime.date(2022, 2, 8), datetime.date(2022, 2, 9), datetime.date(2022, 2, 10), datetime.date(2022, 2, 11), datetime.date(2022, 2, 12),datetime.date(2022, 12, 8), datetime.date(2023, 8, 20), datetime.date(2023, 8, 21), datetime.date(2023, 8, 22), datetime.date(2023, 8, 23), datetime.date(2023, 8, 24), datetime.date(2023, 8, 25), datetime.date(2023, 8, 26), datetime.date(2023, 8, 27), datetime.date(2023, 8, 28), datetime.date(2023, 8, 29), datetime.date(2023, 8, 30), datetime.date(2023, 8, 31), datetime.date(2023, 9, 1), datetime.date(2023, 9, 2), datetime.date(2023, 9, 3), datetime.date(2023, 9, 4), datetime.date(2023, 9, 5), datetime.date(2023, 9, 6), datetime.date(2023, 9, 7), datetime.date(2023, 9, 8), datetime.date(2023, 9, 9)]

y_values = [3521, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 1808.695652173913, 1417.391304347826, 1417.391304347826, 1417.391304347826, 1026.086956521739, 634.782608695652, 243.47826086956502, 0]

# Burndown line graph
line_data = pd.DataFrame({'x': x_values, 'y': y_values})

chart_width = 400
chart_height = 600

known_date_1 = datetime.date(2022, 2, 1)
known_date_2 = datetime.date(2023, 8, 20)

line_data_1 = line_data[line_data['x'] <= known_date_1]
line_data_2 = line_data[line_data['x'] >= known_date_2]

line_chart_1 = alt.Chart(line_data_1).mark_line().encode(
    x=alt.X('x:T', axis=alt.Axis(title='Date', grid=True, ticks=True, tickCount=12,
                                    format='%Y-%m-%d', labelAngle=-45, tickColor='pink', tickSize=10, tickWidth=3)),

    y=alt.Y('y:Q', axis=alt.Axis(title='Tiles'))
)

line_chart_2 = alt.Chart(line_data_2).mark_line().encode(
    x=alt.X('x:T', axis=alt.Axis(title=None, grid=True, ticks=True, tickCount=12,
                                    format='%Y-%m-%d', labelAngle=-45, tickColor='pink', tickSize=10, tickWidth=3)),

    y=alt.Y('y:Q', axis=alt.Axis(title=None, labels=False), scale=alt.Scale(domain=[0, 4000]))
)

full_chart = alt.hconcat(line_chart_1, line_chart_2)

st.altair_chart(full_chart, use_container_width=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting idea! I'll play around with it in a couple of days and get back to you. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: A colleuge of mine said they didn't know of any graphing software that could be able to do somthing like this. I don't really want to change libraries now, but would matpltlib have any options? Or.....

Comment: @Binx i would definitely recommend `plotly` if you want similar hover behavior, and you could do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67104926/plot-discontinued-broken-axis-with-gap-in-the-x-axis-indicating-scale-jump) to achieve a split x-axis. `matplotlib` probably has something similar as well, but hover behavior takes a bit more work to achieve